# How to sort dates by asending order. Dates are like dd/mm/yyyy (31/12/2015) or (dd-MMM-yyyy) format

Tags: jquery, sorting, date

I have scenario like I need to sort dates with different format like `dd/mm/yyyy (31/12/2015)` and `mm/dd/yyyy (12/31/2015)`.

For `mm/dd/yyyy (12/31/2015)` I am using this `sortedKey = sortedKey.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b;})` but how can I sort this format `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: What's the difference supposed to be in your two `sort()` calls? They're identical.

Comment: its not sorting for format like this 31/12/2015 take 20 dates with same format

Comment: So how do you know which format `01/02/2015` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not work with dates in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

If you had dates in **`mm/dd/yyyy`** format, you would be able to **convert strings to `Date` and then compare**:

```js
var arr = ['01-01-2015', '03-03-2015', '07-30-2015', '12-30-2014']; // mm-dd-yyyy

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = new Date(a);
  var bDate = new Date(b);

  return (aDate < bDate ? -1 : 1);
});

document.write(arr.join("<br/>"));
```

The best way to solve this problem is to change the format of dates.

However, **if you cannot change the format of dates**, you can use some hacks like parsing using **regular expressions**:

```js
function parse_ddmmyyyy(str) // example: for str = '07-30-2015'
{
  var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g); // numbers will be [7,30,2015]
  return new Date(numbers[2], numbers[1]-1, numbers[0]); // new Date(2015, 6, 30)
}

// dd-mm-yyyy (dd/mm/yyyy)
var arr = ['01-01-2015', '03-03-2015', '30-07-2015', '30/12/2014', '18/11/2016', '03-11-2014', '02/01/2015']; 

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aDate = parse_ddmmyyyy(a);
  var bDate = parse_ddmmyyyy(b);

  return (aDate < bDate ? -1 : 1);
});

document.write(arr.join("<br/>"));
```

This will work for both `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy`, even mixed.

Comment: can you please give me for mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @SohamShetty The first code snippet works for `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Comment: Thanks and what about this format dd-MMM-yyyy or dd-MMM-yy like 10-jan-2013 or 10-jan-13

Comment: @SohamShetty The first code snipper works for `dd-MMM-yyyy` format as well. Check this JSFiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/3553um1p/

Comment: The problem is that first code giving this like we consider only years 49,50,51,48 like yy then sort is happening like 50,51,48,49 in my app but jfiddle its working fine. 50 considered as 1950 and 49 considered  as 2049. why

Comment: @SohamShetty That's how it works. How should it know what you mean by `50` - 1950 or 2050. If you work with such a large date intervals, you definitely need to use full years (`yyyy`).

Comment: function parse_mmddyyyy(str) // example: for str = '07-30-2015'
{
  var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g); // numbers will be [7,30,2015]
  return new Date(numbers[2], numbers[0],numbers[1]-1); // new Date(2015, 6, 30)
} I used this............................ Thanks for support throughout @YeldarKurmangaliyev

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use match method for this 10-jan-2013 so I can get like 10,jan,2013